# How to enable hibernation on Windows Server 2019?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, hibernation

I have Windows Server 2019. By default, hibernation is disabled. To enable it i tried:

`powercfg -h on`, `powercfg -h -size 75%`, and `powercfg -h -size on`.

Nothing worked. I Also tried to edit the registry:
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power

by setting HibernateEnabled to type REG_DWORD and a value of 0. That didn't enable hibernation.
the command `powercfg \a` gives the following result:

> ```
> The following sleep states are not available on this system:
>     Standby (S1)
>         The system firmware does not support this standby state.
>
>     Standby (S2)
>         The system firmware does not support this standby state.
>
>     Standby (S3)
>         The system firmware does not support this standby state.
>
>     Hibernate
>         The system firmware does not support hibernation.
>
>     Standby (S0 Low Power Idle)
>         The system firmware does not support this standby state.
>
>     Hybrid Sleep
>         Standby (S3) is not available.
>         Hibernation is not available.
>
>     Fast Startup
>         Hibernation is not available.
> ```

How to fix that and enable hibernation?

Comment: see: [How to disable and re-enable hibernation on a computer that is running Windows (learn.microsoft.com)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/deployment/disable-and-re-enable-hibernation). But with "The system firmware does not support hibernation." you need to look at superuser.com: https://superuser.com/a/1373973/421114

Comment: Why did you set HibernateEnabled to ZERO?